# Youtube sends wrong expires date

Tags: http, youtube, expires-header

I loaded an Youtube video, and was checking the Network tab in the Chrome inspector. The weird part is the response header **expires** show a wrong date, see:

expires:Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST

Does some one understand if this is correctly implemented (some solution as "the response already arrives expired for security reasons") or is just a bug?

The entire request-response pair:

```
General
    Request URL:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2bcZpjbimc
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 
    Remote Address:216.58.222.14:443

Response Headers
    alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
    cache-control:no-cache
    content-encoding:gzip
    content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    date:Mon, 16 Jan 2017 02:12:59 GMT
    expires:Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
    server:YouTubeFrontEnd
    status:200
    strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000
    x-content-type-options:nosniff
    x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
    x-xss-protection:1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube

Request Headers
    :authority:www.youtube.com
    :method:GET
    :path:/watch?v=Y2bcZpjbimc
    :scheme:https
    accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    cache-control:max-age=0
    cookie:YSC=tkkR7-gquIo; LOGIN_INFO=09a68a7966aeeb4c54ea2812d67ef17bcz4AAAB7IjMiOiA5ODI4NjMwLCAiMSI6IDEsICI4IjogMTUxMjAxNzQ2Mjg1LCAiNyI6IDAsICI0IjogIkdBSUEifQ==; llbcs=0; SID=KgRtjV-NqZqWb_Vtlx1ZVI4BGeOq6TO0kOwRjM63Y9zRlD8NZ14Ain0S7OHEdAude6Ql5w.; HSID=Ae2Oerx0Cx8cLGNN2; SSID=AAxm-sCogA2PcrWj-; APISID=l63qqbTbXYbA1SWI/ATu8oD872iyWdvAgn; SAPISID=jEgCzttgmiin9s_R/A0u9gLEfrGesFDkOu; _ga=GA1.2.1081395761.1467350952; wide=1; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=9ZvTZmoHPqs; C_YNe.resume=nPTuJcnwLro:132,CG1HnKT8khI:1282,0SARbwvhupQ:527; PREF=f1=50000000&f5=20030&al=en+pt&cvdm=grid
    dnt:1
    upgrade-insecure-requests:1
    user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
    x-client-data:CJG2yQEIprbJAQipncoB

Query String Parameters
    v:Y2bcZpjbimc
```

Answer (score -1):

It is an easter egg left by the original author.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?